# Can I use INJECT_EVENTS to automate another app?

Tags: android, root

I've seen (but know nothing about) the android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS permission. If I have a rooted device, can I write an app using this to automate another app? Or is this something that is usually disabled in actual released hardware? Or is my impression of what the permission means completely wrong?

I'm just wondering if this is something worth spending time to learn about.

If I could do it, the goal would be to automate Nikon's camera app on the S800c camera. They have annoyingly neglected to make all the camera features available in the Camera API implementation on this device, but if there is some hope I could automate the camera app, I might be able to use it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I have a rooted device, can I write an app using this to automate another app?

Only if you are creating your own firmware. `INJECT_EVENTS` is a `signature` level permission, meaning that the APK requesting the permission must be signed by the same signing key that signed the firmware. Having root has no effect on this, other than increasing your ability to perhaps run alternative firmware, if there is any for this device.

Beyond that, you would then have to track down what it is in Android that protects itself via `INJECT_EVENTS`.

> They have annoyingly neglected to make all the camera features available in the Camera API implementation on this device

That doesn't sound good. If you don't mind my asking, what specifically are you referring to?

Comment: Good to know. I don't have to worry about figuring out how to use it then :-). The main thing that is missing in Nikon's integration of camera and android is the ability to access the full resolution of the camera. If you ask the Camera class for the available image sizes, it reports 3264x2448 as the max size (8 MP), but the nikon camera app can take pictures up to 16 MP (4608x3456). I've seen another developer claim there is no access to the hardware zoom settings as well.

Comment: Mark is correct in regards to the INJECT_EVENTS permission. However you can inject keys by writing to /dev/input/eventX directly . This requires setting the permission to writable, so only possible if you android is rooted. I can provide an example if you still need it.